# Something is wrong with my python code but i cant find it

Tags: python

```
num_children = int(input("Enter the number of children in the family: "))

for i in range(num_children):
    print("For child", i+1)
    age = int(input("Enter the age of child (0-17) :" ))
    
    if age  >= 0 and age <= 17 :
        deposit_amount = float(input("Enter the fixed monthly deposit amount ($200-$600): "))
        
        if deposit_amount >=200 and deposit_amount <=600:
            if age == 0:
                monthly_interest = 0.005
            
            else:
                monthly_interest = 0.004
            
            accumulate = 0
            total_deposits = 0
            accumulated_before_this_month = 0
        
            for month in range(age * 12):
            
                accumulated =  accumulated_before_this_month
                total_deposits += deposit_amount + (accumulated_before_this_month * monthly_interest) + deposit_amount
                accumulated_before_this_month = accumulated 
                accumulated_amount = int(accumulated)
           
            print("\nFor Child", i+1, ": ")
            print("Total amount of money accumulated until age 18:  $",accumulated_amount)
            print("Total amount of money deposited by the family until age 18:  $", total_deposits)
        
        else:
            print("Enter a valid invesment")
    else:
        print("Enter valid age !")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\emire\downloads\untitled0.py:53
    print("Total amount of money accumulated until age 18:  $",accumulated_amount)

NameError: name 'accumulated_amount' is not defined
```

I wasn't able to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
accumulated_amount = 0
```

in line number 1

Comment: Bad question, but personally think it might be better to recommend "var: int".

Comment: @TimothyH I think you might have your languages mixed up; this question is in Python. That would just type-hint `var` as an `int`; `accumulated_value` would still raise a `NameError`. Even `var` would do so.

Comment: I thought I remembered from the docs that it initializes to zero value, checking might have been just a proposal

Comment: Python 3.12 has that behavior, I'm remembering that but it must have not been implemented that way or otherwise changed, that might have turned out annoying for me

Comment: Oh, fascinating! I didn't know that. We've both learned something today. : )

Answer (score 1):

I assume You get this error whenever you set the child age to 0. Then the loop

```
for month in range(age * 12):
```

doesn't run and *accumulated_amount* is defined there. You need to either define it outside of the loop, or create a case for a child being 0 years old, or edit the loop such that it runs if age = 0.